# What is the name of this method that computes the mod of big exponents?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was studying Discrete Math by the DVD course of the professor [Arthur Benjamin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_T._Benjamin), and in one of his lectures He shows a method called "Seed planting" to calculate big exponents mod some number, He explained why this method work But I didn't get it.

I searched the name of that method and I found nothing, I don't know if It is a nickname for the method, But I'd like to know if it is really a method known that I can use without fear.

$6^{83}$ mod $79$

the method begins by doing sucessive squaring.

$6, 6^2, 6^4, 6^8, 6^{16}, 6^{32}, 6^{64}$

$83 = 64 + 16 + 2+ 1$

Then you keep squaring, But everytime You bump into a red number, You multiply by the base, apart from the first number.

$\color{red}{64}$ 6

$32$ $6^2$ (mod $79)$ $ = 36$

$\color{red}{16}$ $\left(36\right)^2\ \cdot 6\ =\ 7776\ =\ 34\ \left(\operatorname{mod}\ 79\right)$

$8$ $\left(34\right)^2\ =\ 1156\ =\ 50\ \left(\operatorname{mod}\ 79\right)$

$4$ $\left(50\right)^2\ =\ 2500\ =\ 51\ \left(\operatorname{mod}\ 79\right)$

$\color{red}{2}$ $\left(51\right)^2\ \cdot 6 =15606\ =43\ \left(\operatorname{mod}\ 79\right)$

$\color{red}{1}$ $\left(43\right)^2\ \cdot 6=11094=34\ \left(\operatorname{mod}\ 79\right)$

Comment: This is called [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks

Comment: In Mathematica, the function is implemented as PowerMod[x,a,n]